# Convert UML class association "1 to n" to java code

Tags: java, uml, reverse-engineering

I have to do reverse engineering from UML class diagram to java code. Here's an example:

[image]

As you can see, a SCSIController can have 1..4 DiskDrive. Can i represent it in java this way?

```
public class SCSIController extends Controller{
    private List disks;

    public SCSIController(){
        disks=new ArrayList();
    }

    public void addDisk(DiskDrive d){
        if(disks.size()<4 && !disks.contains(d)){
            disks.add(d);
            ………
            ………
        }else
             ……… //do something else
    }
}
```

Before adding a DiskDrive to SCSIController, i check that the SCSIController has less than 4 DiskDrive in his disks list. Is this the right way to code this 1 to n association?

Comment: Since you know the actual number up front, maybe an array would be easier. DiskDrive drives = new DiskDrive[4];

Comment: If I use an array, do I need a counter to know how many elements are effectively in the array?

Comment: you can't do myArray.add(...), so when adding an element, you'jll need to know what index to put it in.

Comment: You could add a private static variable and increment it insides the addDisk method if you want to use the array data structure. However, I would opt for an HashSet data structure because in principle it doesn't accept duplicates. Secondly, you can initialize this set with 4 elements (HashSet(4)<>), performance first of all :-)

Comment: @Stultuske I know, that's why I asked if I need a counter. For example, using an array, i can add an integer attribute  'nelem' initialized to 0 in the constructor and in the add method i can check if nelem<4. If nelem<4 i insert the element in the array and increase nelem of 1. Obviously i need to decrease nelem of 1 when i remove an element. Is it right?

Comment: there is no need for a counter. you can create your own add method, and just search for the first index with a nullvalue

Comment: Ah ok!  So when i'll 'remove' an element i'll simply set it's index to null value. Thank you

Comment: Minor point — technically this is forward engineering; reverse engineering would be taking the Java source code and extracting a model from it. The terms come from model driven software development, an approach where you build a model and generate (forward engineer) source code from it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your are correct. However, your multiplicity does not require uniqueness

[image]

though it will make a lot of sense :-) Going strictly with the UML spec you could omit `&& !disks.contains(d))` from your code. Or you add the type like shown above. (Or probably just assume that people are able to recognize that the right way.)

Side note: I think a SCSIController can as well have attached no drive. Your UML shows `1..4` so you'd need at least one drive which makes your code wrong in that respect.

Comment: Do you think i can solve using the constructor public SCSIController(DiskDrive d){disks=new ArrayList();disks.add(d);} ?

Comment: That would be a solution. From a practical experience I'd argue with the UML author that it should rather be `0..4`.